# When Zooming out my website, everything looks wrong

Tags: html, css, header, structure

If you zoom out my website, the structure of the header looks bad. I don't know what to do about this. [This is the link of my website](http://danithemes.fanscity.eu). [This is the CSS and HTML structure.](http://pastebin.com/RaEd1izQ) Hope you can help me, I really need help :(

Comment: set background-repeat:none; to your images

Comment: Do you mean that the header is pulling to the left?

Comment: Do you want to horizontal center your header banner?

Comment: @Alan Yes, that's right, the header It's on the left and I want it to be on the center

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want you header to stay in the centre with your content, you will need t do that, it doesn't just happen.

You should start by agreeing on a width you want you content in (you have `width: 1100px`on your container div, so I'll go with that for you.)

In you css for `.container`change `width: 1100px;` to `max-width: 1100px`.

Then in the css for `#header` remove the `position: absolute;`. Add in `max-width: 1100px; margin: 0 auto;`

Comment: GREAT! I just have to adjust the header size. I worked perfectly! Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem, up vote the answer next to the green tick so others know it is the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to modify the structure of your HTML and place the `header` div inside the `container` div. Currently, that part of your HTML is like this:

```
<div id="header"></div>

<div id="container">
     <div id="content"></div>
     <div id="navigationposition"></div>
     <div id="position"></div>
</div>
```

but it should be like this instead:

```
<div id="container">
     <div id="header"></div> 
     <div id="content"></div>
     <div id="navigationposition"></div>
     <div id="position"></div>
</div>
```

After modifying your HTML, you can add the following CSS to your stylesheet:

```
#header {
     margin-left: -100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your header is positioned absolute
so when you  zoom in and out it will stay absolute positioned. In the top left corner when the page is zoomed out

Also you do not have a wrapper for your code.... you may want to wrap everything in a container,
This will also take care of the image size thats over lapping your other content.

I do not know id you wanted the header to overlap like that but if it was intended just use margin-left

a wrapper will also contain your other divs sizes to stay within that wrapper.

### Not going to work with zooming in and out

```
#header {
position:absolute;
z-index:101
}

<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">

    </div>

    <div id="underheader">

    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

### css

```
#wrapper{
  width:800px;
} or whatever width you want

#header{
  maegin-left:50px;
} or whatever px you desire
```